# jQuery Mobile Add 2 Buttons In List Item

Tags: jquery, listview, button, mobile, append

Does anyone know how to add buttons to a list item in jQuery Mobile. I tried the following but it doesn't work.

HTML

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

JS

```
$('#list').append('<li><h3>Hello</h3><a id="1" data-role="button" data-icon="check" /><a id="2" data-role="button data-icon="delete" /></li');
```

The code has to be appended because I am getting data from an ajax call and appending it...I also need two buttons which I added in the JS code above.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6bCYe/)

Comment: check this link: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-split.html

Comment: Hi, but is there a way to have two button splits in a single list item

Answer (score 0):

instead of using data-role="button" following example would suit your requirement.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chamarajanaka/JLVcj/

Comment: Im sorry if my question wasn't clear enough but I want two buttons the right side of every list item